# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, inputstream, tar, compression

Testing my tar.gz extraction tool, I found thrown the exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at it.uniroma2.informatica.specialistica.IO.ScanCompressedFileUtil.main(ScanCompressedFileUtil.java:60
```

So the code at line 60 is:

```
BufferedReader bufLe= reader.remove();
try {
  while ( bufLe.ready() ){
    System.out.println(" "+bufLe.readLine());
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where calling *buffer.readLine()*, throws the exception. When I open the tar.gz, I kept the stream of all single file, like BuffReader then I put them to a linkedList, and then i Closed the buffer of the file tar.gz opened.

But When I pop an element within the linked list and then try to read line by line, I have the execption.

Why do I have this exception? Maybe I am wrong somethinh when I iterate through the files within the tar.gz?

To doing so, I have the code:

```
TarInputStream is =  new TarInputStream(gzipInputStream);

TarEntry entryx = null;

try {
  while((entryx = is.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    InputStream tmpInx = new StreamingTarEntry(is,  entryx.getSize());
    // questo viene invocato perchè il file da lettere è un file txt
    manageTxtinsideTAR(tmpInx , buffer);
    // I add the stream to a linked list
```

THe class STREAMINGTARENTRY,  extends FilterInputStream, so it's only wraps the stream.

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to your problem, but you shouldn't use the ready method of BufferedReader like this. Read its api documentation. To read everything from a BufferedReader, line by line, call readLine until it returns null.

Comment: NO I'm sorry. The problem is not related to use of .ready(). Because a have implemented two type of application. ON my first application all works well. But if i want's all single file like BuffeREader, and then a I retrieve one's of them, i have the exception.

Answer (score 5):

It could be related to the JVM bug https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=53ede10dc8803210b03577eac43?bug_id=6519463

See my answer for more details on this related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18845169/2463453

Comment: +1 - If this is the problem, the solutions are either to update to a more recent release of Java 7, or to catch and ignore the `EOFException` ... as a workaround for the buggy JVM behaviour.