# java extract zip Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java

I am creating a program that will extract a zip and then insert the files into a database, every so often I get the error

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

I can not pinpoint the reason for this as the extraction code is pretty much the same as all the other code you can find on the web. My code is as follows:

```
public void extract(String zipName, InputStream content) throws Exception {

    int BUFFER = 2048;

    //create the zipinputstream 
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(content);

    //Get the name of the zip
    String containerName = zipName;

    //container for the zip entry
    ZipEntry entry;

    // Process each entry
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        //get the entry file name
        String currentEntry = entry.getName();

        try {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // establish buffer for writing file
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
                int currentByte;

                // read and write until last byte is encountered
                while ((currentByte = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {

                    baos.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }

                baos.flush(); //flush the buffer 

                //this method inserts the file into the database
                insertZipEntry(baos.toByteArray());

                baos.close();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR WITHIN ZIP " + containerName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: • Have you checked that ZIP stream (file) you try to process is valid one (e.g. `unzip` can unpack it)? • Please pinpoint the line in code that actually raised the exception.

Comment: I may not remember correctly but aren't you supposed to close each entry after processing it?

Comment: You should close the baos before calling insertZipEntry(), and our 'currentByte' variable is poorly named: should be 'count' or similar.

Comment: Can you pick a best answer for your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by this [JVM bug (JVM-6519463)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=53ede10dc8803210b03577eac43?bug_id=6519463)

I previously has about one or two errors on 1000 randomly created documents, I applied the proposed solution (catch EOFException and do nothing with it) and I have no more errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are occasionally being given truncated Zip files to process. Check upstream.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception and the problem was in the compressing method (not extracting). I did not close the ZipOutputStream with `zos.closeEntry()` after writing to the output stream. Without that, compressing worked well but I got an exception while extracting.

```
public static byte[] zip(String outputFilename, byte[] output) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(outputFilename));
        zos.write(output, 0, output.length);            
        zos.closeEntry(); //this line must be here
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //catch exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Never attempt to read more bytes than the entry contains. Call ZipEntry.getSize() to get the actual size of the entry, then use this value to keep track of the number of bytes remaining in the entry while reading from it. See below :

```
try{    

   ...

   int bytesLeft = (int)entry.getSize();
   while ( bytesLeft>0 && (currentByte=zis.read(data, 0, Math.min(BUFFER, bytesLeft))) != -1) {
     ...
  }

  ...

  }
```

Comment: That's not necessary. The ZipInputStream takes care of that for you.

Comment: EJP: and yet it fails. However, both entry.getSize() and entry.getCompressedSize() return -1 for me.

Comment: @Buffalo It fails because the input is truncated, and this technique does not and cannot possibly solve that.